# Laptop screen goes black, but laptop still running

Tags: 14.04, intel-graphics, youtube, gpu, crash

I have an old Asus laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Sometimes the laptop's screen goes black, but the laptop keeps running. It happens when loading a youtube video or websites like GDrive, but not all the time.
In case of Youtube it begins to load, then everything crashes and after a few seconds the screen goes black. Then I can hear the sound of the youtube video for a few seconds, but that also stops and I have to restart the laptop. 
I think the problem could be with the GPU because the laptop crashes when loading graphics heavy websites.
I tried to update the graphics driver, but that didn't help.
Please help me!

NOTE: This problem didn't appear after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04.

Here are the details about the laptop:[image]

Comment: How much memory is being used when your computer is idle? It may be running out of memory.

Comment: It uses around 300 MB when the computer is idle.

Comment: I had a similar issue before. In my case, I could drop to console 1 with Ctrl-Alt-F1 and back to the GUI with Ctrl-Alt-F7 and everything would be fine again. Some downstream distros seem to use Ctrl-Alt-F8 for the GUI.

Comment: 14.04 fixed the problem? any log messages give any clues?