# Ubuntu screen goes black after loading youtube

Tags: 14.04, video, flash, screen, youtube

While loading YouTube videos on Ubuntu 14.4 my screen goes black and yet everything still works, lights on the keyboard and the video plays. No amount of pressing buttons (ctrl+alt+f1, power button, mouse clicks etc..) can get the screen to turn on again. I've had ubuntu 14.4 for a few months now and this error started appearing yesterday and continues to black screen whenever i load YouTube.

The only fix I can find is by hard shutting down the computer and restarting. That gets the screen to work, yet if i load youtube it repeats.

My computer (laptop) is fairly old now and it maybe be a hardware error, yet i've been on 14.4 for a few months now and unless it was a new update i doubt it's my hardware.

I'm not the only one having this problem: 
[Laptop screen goes black, but laptop still running](https://askubuntu.com/questions/534883/laptop-screen-goes-black-but-laptop-still-running)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/538392/laptop-running-ubuntu-14-04-screen-goes-black-while-playing-youtube-videos

I believe this error needs serious attention now and it may be due to a recent update as most people who have this error have posted on it recently.

Here are my pc specs: [http://i.imgur.com/YlsHtuH](https://i.imgur.com/YlsHtuH)

I'm willing to provide any information possible and thanks in advance for your interest in this problem!

edit: I have found that if i don't have the tab with the video open, the screen doesn't black out.
-des

Comment: Same problem here on an old Dell Inspiron. Started about 1-2 weeks ago. Both Chrome and Firefox have the issue.

Comment: Switch off hardware graphics acceleration in the Chrome settings. chrome://settings/ -> 'advanced settings' -> untick 'use hardware acceleration'. Then restart Chrome. Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

As @AE indicates you can turn off hardware acceleration in chrome in the settings by chrome://settings/ -> 'advanced settings' -> untick 'use hardware acceleration' and restart chrome.

In Firefox It's here:

[image: firefox-disable-accel]

A restart may be required here as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem maybe caused by adobe-flash. You can update your adobe flash plugin(https://get.adobe.com/cn/flashplayer/) or watch Youtube videos in a html5 format(recommended).(turn it on at https://www.youtube.com/html5)

Hope can help you.