# Black Screen when playing YouTube Videos

Tags: unity, compiz, video, youtube, crash

The computer is a Toshiba Satelite Pro U300. It's worked fine up until a recent update about a week or two ago.

When I try to play YouTube videos, the whole monitor goes black, and the computer seems to be unresponsive. If I close/lower the laptop screen until the system goes to sleep (the video stops playing music), then open it up again and wait for it to wake up, I can watch the rest of the video, but Unity or Compiz has crashed-- so only as much as has been cached.

No title bars are present, I can't use keyboard shortcuts to open terminal, there's no access to the application menu/bar. I can't reconnect to the Internet because of the missing command bar/tray at the top.

If I then press control-alt-f1 and try to restart unity with various commands I've found, I am unable to get it to run at all:

```
unity &> /dev/null & disown
```

Doesn't seem to have an effect.

I've also tried

```
killall unity-panel-service
compiz --replace
unity &
unity --replace
setsid unity
killall -u USR1 -r -g unity*
```

I've tried reinstalling graphics drivers. I have tried reinstalling Unity. I have tried reinstalling Ubuntu desktop.

The only thing left is to hard-reset with the power button (or from control-alt-f1 with sudo shutdown -f)

I don't know what else to try. I've found a few other questions on Ask Ubuntu that also have no solutions, so I'm hoping that my increased level of detail will attract some wonderfully talented individual to make everyone happy! :)

Thanks so much.

Similar Issues:

[Laptop screen goes black, but laptop still running](https://askubuntu.com/questions/534883/laptop-screen-goes-black-but-laptop-still-running)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/538392/laptop-running-ubuntu-14-04-screen-goes-black-while-playing-youtube-videos

[Ubuntu screen goes black after loading youtube](https://askubuntu.com/questions/540910/ubuntu-screen-goes-black-after-loading-youtube)

UPDATE November 22

I tried to reformat the machine and use a different distribution to determine if this was a hardware issue. Crunchbang ran without any problems, (and is really fast!) This is my wife's machine, and she preferred Ubuntu, so I thought why not try one more time with a fresh install. The problem was worse after the fresh install of Ubuntu, so we're now back to Crunchbang This can't be a hardware issue, and there must be a driver problem for the monitor. I suspect Ubuntu doesn't care much about old hardware.

Comment: sudo apt-get install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra This will fix your issue

Comment: @Lonston -- I don't think so; I have the same issue. I tried that and got 'chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra is already the newest version'.